# std::thread error (thread not member of std)

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, std

I compiled & installed gcc4.4 using macports.

When I try to compile using -> g++ -g -Wall -ansi -pthread -std=c++0x main.cpp...:

```
 #include <thread>
 ...
  std::thread t(handle);
  t.join();
 ....
```

The compiler returns:

```
 cserver.cpp: In member function 'int CServer::run()':
 cserver.cpp:48: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
 cserver.cpp:48: error: expected ';' before 't'
 cserver.cpp:49: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
```

But `std::cout <<...` compiles fine..

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you look in the thread header, it appears that the class only exists `#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)`. I'm not sure though, what you'd have to do to have those defined.

Comment: @UncleBens: I believe those are directly defined by -pthread and -std=c++0x. Omitting -pthread causes a seg fault: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-04/msg00208.html

Comment: Just the latest update: MacPorts gcc 4.7.0 supports/compiles std::thread, while 4.6.3 does not.

Answer (score 15):

gcc does not fully support std::thread yet:

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Use [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) in the meantime.

**Edit**

Although the following compiled and ran fine for me with gcc 4.4.3:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct F
{
  void operator() () const
  {
    std::cout<<"Printing from another thread"<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  F f;
  std::thread t(f);
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++0x -pthread main.cpp
```

Output of `a.out`:

```
Printing from another thread
```

Can you provide the full code? Maybe there's some obscure issue lurking in those `...`s?

Comment: I tried your code and I get the same error...
Can this be OSX related? Or maybe something that isn't right with the GCC install by MacPorts?

Comment: It may be that MacPorts doesn't fully support c++0x functionality? Do you have the output from your gcc configure script? Here's one Mac user for whom configure specified that std::thread is not supported: (http://www.mail-archive.com/dealii@dealii.org/msg00973.html)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on windows using MinGW. I found wrapper classes for in on github [mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads) Including
mingw.mutex.h, mingw.thread.h files to global MinGW directory fixed this issue. All I had to do is to include header file and my code stayed the same

```
#include "mingw.thread.h"

...
std::thread t(handle);
...
```

Comment: Cheers for this. Was driving me crazy. Your answer was slightly confusing where you referred to the global MinGW directory. I had to drop the files in the project folder where all the other .h files are to get it work... but it worked.

Comment: Well what do you mean global directory, I am trying to find where to insert it tried globally same level with /bin /include doesn't work. thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Drop **-ansi**, it means -std=c++98, which you obviously don't want. It also causes macro `__STRICT_ANSI__` to be defined and this may change the behavior of the headers, e.g. by disabling C++0x support.

Comment: The macro name actually has two underscores at the end, but SO misinterprets it as formatting if I write it correctly.

Comment: Well pointed out, I removed it, but it still gives me the same error.. I tried with gcc4.4 and gcc4.5 beta... This is frustrating.

Comment: fixed the missing underscore problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update your MinGW compiler to the latest version by using MSYS2 for this error or try reinstalling MinGW by using MSYS2**

```
cserver.cpp:48: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
```