# C++11 with gcc 4.6.1 on a mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11

I'm new to the mac and trying to get gcc 4.6 working.

I installed MacPorts and installed gcc 4.6.1 (by executing `sudo port install gcc46`). I'm trying to compile a simple test code that compiles fine on Linux (with gcc 4.6.1 and 4.6.2) and Windows, but I'm getting errors that make me thing there is something wrong with the installed libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <future>

struct test {
    void get() {}
};

/*template<typename Func>
test async(const Func &f) {
    f();
    return test();
}*/

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto t1 = async([]() -> int{
        cout << "This is thread 1" << endl;
        return 1;
    });

    auto t2 = async([]() -> int {
        cout << "This is thread 2" << endl;
        return 2;
    });

    std::cout << "This is the main thread" << endl;

    t1.get();
    t2.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The error messages:

```
macbook01:Test fozi$ g++ main.cpp -o test -std=c++0x
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
main.cpp:30:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::enable_if<true, std::future<int> >::type'
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::enable_if<true, std::future<int> >::type'
main.cpp:30:6: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '<expression error>'
main.cpp:35:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::enable_if<true, std::future<int> >::type'
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::enable_if<true, std::future<int> >::type'
main.cpp:35:6: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '<expression error>'
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/future: At global scope:
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/future:150:5: error: 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, std::launch>::value), std::future<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...))> >::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>, _Args = {}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, std::launch>::value), std::future<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...))> >::type = std::future<int>]', declared using local type 'main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/future:150:5: error: 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, std::launch>::value), std::future<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...))> >::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>, _Args = {}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, std::launch>::value), std::future<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...))> >::type = std::future<int>]', declared using local type 'main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

Note that if I use my dummy async function it compiles and runs fine.

I'm kind of stuck, do I have to install a specific library (version)? How do I do that?

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you're taking the headers from the correct path? You can run gcc with `-H` to see where the headers come from. I've previously built GCC 4.6.0 from source on MacOS, with no problems.

Comment: I actually tried to fix them and saw the changes, so yes, I'm pretty sure I'm using the right libraries.

Comment: You have a strange `future` include file. In mine, lines 111 and 150 don't seem  to be related to `std::enable_if` (I have 4.6.1 too). Perhaps it's corrupted.

Comment: Do you still use the g++ command? In such case it may not have been replaced. Try g++ --version to get the actual version you are using.
Also, if you get only the compiler nothing says that you have the libraries too... Or perhaps you have to include them separately (try -v flag to see include header pathes)

Comment: Mac has no future, j/k ... I thought MacPorts GCC had some issues with C++0x does Apple GCC still not support lambdas?

Comment: Apple gcc is 4.2 - so no lambda support

Comment: Also the macports gcc46 is effectively 4.6.0 not 4.6.1 (I think it is actually a release candidate from the release date 25/03/11)

Comment: @Mark that could explain the file differences. I tried to update the header files to 4.6.2 but it failed as well. I didn't succeed to build gcc 4.6.2 on the mac.

Comment: 4.6.2 is not released yet so I would stick to 4.6.1 unless you want to debug the compiler

Comment: A collegue managed to build 4.6.1 on a diffrent machine but it failed to compile my test as well. It doesn't look like this is a problem with my installation. Has anyone tried to compile the code I posted?

Comment: Compiles fine on 4.6.0 20110505 on OpenSUSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We're getting there

gcc 4.7 (port) compiles this code just fine.

Xcode 4.3 comes with clang 3.1 which is supposed to support this, but it crashes when I try to compile. However I built clang from SVN and replaced the compiler Xcode is using and now it compiles and runs fine as well.

And it only took half a year.

Answer (score 5):

I've had similar issues with gcc-4.6.1 and OS X 10.6. The problem is C++0x's thread is not supported at the moment on OS X.

See this post: [c++0x, std::thread error (thread not member of std)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/c0x-stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std)

If you look in "${prefix}/include/c++/4.6.1/future" header file, you'll see the line:

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1) \
        && defined(_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_4)
```

Unfortunately, _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS evalute to 0 on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try `g++ -v` to get the version of G++ you're using. I'm not using a pre-compiled compiler but perhaps it is the same for you.

The GCC 4.6.0 is installed in `/usr/local/bin` under the name `x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0-g++`

If you still use the simple g++ command, it may still be `/usr/bin/g++`, which is Apple's llvm-gcc flavor.

Comment: wanted to post it as a comment, sorry :s

Comment: I'm starting g++ from a terminal, so yes, I'm sure the version is correct. Also, I renamed the originals to gcc-4.2 and so on and am using symbolic links to switch them around. That includes the ones in /Development.