# std::async on GCC 4.7.2 (cygwin) fails with "invalid use of incomplete type"

Tags: c++11, lambda, g++, cygwin, incomplete-type

On GCC 4.7.2 (on cygwin, [compiled from source](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC#Build_and_Install_GCC)) using `std::async` fails with

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type
```

of some `std::__async_sfinae_helper`. I am out of luck and appreciate your help.

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
  std::async([]{});
}
```

fails with

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x    future.cpp   -o future
future.cpp: In function 'int main()':
future.cpp:5:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<void>}'
In file included from future.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<void>}'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future: At global scope:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:187:5: error: 'typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type = std::future<void>]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
<builtin>: recipe for target `future' failed
```

Version information

```
% g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)
```

[c++11 std::async doesn't work in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209871/c11-stdasync-doesnt-work-in-mingw) did not help because neither am I using mingw, nor is the thread model win32.

Comment: I think it is related to the problem related on mingw question, did you tried to see whether _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS is defined or not? Here on cygwin and gcc 4.5.3 it is not defined and I got the same error message. Another one related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177887/

Comment: Did you try compiler key `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yes, no success, same error.