# How to compile the code using #include <thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to compile some C++ code that uses threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void hello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello Concurrent World\n";
}

int _main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I get errors when compiling:

```
c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open 
include file: 'thread': No such file or directory


~/Documents/C++ $ g++ -o thread1 thread1.cpp -D_REENTRANT -lpthread
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/thread:35:0,
                 from thread1.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file 
requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, 
C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with 
the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/c0x-stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<thread>` and standard threading support is a new feature (defined in the C++11 standard). As for g++, you have to enable it adding `-std=c++0x` to the command line, as explained in the error message.

Also, you are using a nonstandard (Microsoft-specific) main, use the "classic" `main` and normal `char`:

```
// thread1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void hello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello Concurrent World\n";
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that not all C++11 features are available in current compilers; as far as g++ is concerned, you can find the status of their implementation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: @AlphaBravo: not exactly, there are [some guarantees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6374525/214671); besides, in this specific case there's only one thread using it, so it's safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the header file `<thread>` is only standard in the C++11 newest standard (finalized this year only).

With GCC, you'll need the very latest **4.6** version, and even with it, not everything is supported of the C++11 standard. See [this table](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as MSVC goes, the C++11  `<thread>` header isn't supported in VS2010 - you'll need to pull down a Developer Preview of Visual Studio 11 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh127353) to try it out today.

See [C++11 Features in Visual C++ 11](https://web.archive.org/web/20120521065811/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) for details on what is new in C++ for Visual Studio 11.

Also, my PDF of the book (which is in pre-release at the moment) has the following definition of `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
}
```

which avoids the problems you're running into with `_TCHAR` being undefined in GCC.