# g++ libstdc++-v3 ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++11, gcc

I am building gcc 9.10 and it works great with c threads but im doing something wrong with g++ and libstdc++-v3 I just dont know what.

I compile gcc/g++, glibc, and libstdc++-v3
I see that the file  at include/c++/9.1.0/threads
When I go to compile a simple test program I get

```
error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

C pthread test program compiles

```
#include <pthread.h>
int main(){
    tpthread_t t;
}
```

C  test program compiles

```
#include <threads.h>
int main(){
    thrd_t t;
}
```

Cxx test program does not compile

```
#include <thread>
int main(){
    std::thread t;
}
```

Gets error

```
error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Looking into the header include/c++/9.1.0/threads

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS)
```

it looks like it skips everything if that is not defined
how can I check to see if thats the case and then why?

I made this little test and it compiles indicating to me that _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS is not defined

```
int main(){
    #if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS)
    123 here error
    #endif
}
```

when compiling libstdc++-v3 I use

```
../libstdc++-v3/configure -v --enable-libstdcxx-threads=yes
```

even though I would think threads should be enabled by default on a linux x64 system

The other question doesnt help my situation it was from a long time ago and gcc has changed. One comment looks like it touches on my issue but doesnt go any deeper

```
If you look in the thread header, it appears that the class only exists #if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1). I'm not sure though, what you'd have to do to have those defined
```

Thats the issue im having but theres no solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::thread error (thread not member of std)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std)

Comment: I believe that may have been showing the same error but a different cause. Gcc has threads now by default, im not using -ansi, and not cross compiling. I can use the ubuntu version 7.4 and compile the cxx test so im thinking something wrong with my configuration

Comment: @jeff8j Can you please mention the command that you are running for compilation?

Comment: Adding --enable-threads=yes is what I was missing
../libstdc++-v3/configure -v --enable-threads=yes --disable-multilib
make -j 8
make install

The tests work now and compile as they should with
g++ test.cxx

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to configure with --enable-threads=yes I dont know why that was so hard to find and why thats not default