# namespace "std" has no member "mutex"

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, g++, mutex, mingw-w64

I'm using mingw64 and even a simple program like this failed to compile. Moreover g++ is suggesting a revolutionary solution.

The code-

```
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
  std::mutex m;
}
```

The error-

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:5:8: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
   std::mutex m;
    ^~~~~
```

The solution-

```
test.cpp:5:8: note: 'std::mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to'#include <mutex>'?
test.cpp:2:1:
+#include <mutex>
 
test.cpp:5:8:
   std::mutex m;
        ^~~~~
```

How do I compile this?

Comment: What compiler version and C++ standard are you using? `std::mutex` is only available in C++11 or later

Comment: Also, are you certain that you saved your source file before compiling?

Comment: I was looking a source code in vs code and I encountered bunch of such errors regarding std::mutex and std::thread. So, I tested the above program certainly saving it!

Comment: How do you compile? Have you specified `-std=c++11`?

Comment: g++ test.cpp -std=c++11

Comment: What does `g++ --version` say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std
This is similar. gcc does not fully support std::thread yet. Is std::mutex fully supported by gcc?

Comment: @TedLyngmo g++ --version says "g++.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0"

By the way, can you compile?

Comment: I see. It seems like there's something wrong with the mingw version of g++ then. Standard `g++` have had `std::mutex` for a very long time. Long before 8.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

**C++11 or C11 Multithreading features are only supported by POSIX threads**

Threading I am using is win32 which does not support Multithreading. So, `std::thread` and `std::mutex` will not work!

However to get `std::thread` working, use [this mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads).

I simply replaced my initial mingw installation with x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z

You may find binaries [here](https://github.com/rcpacini/mingw-w64).